# Angular App with Cordova, which adal Version?

Tags: angular, cordova, azure, adal.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to Angular. So I want to create an Angular application, which should be compiled with Cordova later on.

This step already works. But now, I want to authenticate against Microsoft Graph and I don't know which version of adal.js to use ? The Angular one, oder the Apache Cordova one ?

I set up the application in Azure, declared as Web-Application. With a standard HTML / Javascript application the authentication with (standard) adal.js works already fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to use ADAL JS in Cordova apps ,but it is recommend to use the [ADAL cordova plugin](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova), the Cordova plugin for ADAL does not have to cope with limitations if you use ADAL js in Cordova apps(browser sandboxing, absence of refresh token in the implicit flow...), and it grants you far more access to the advanced authentication capabilities of the devices themselves. Please read [this blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/04/06/adal-plugin-for-apache-cordova-deep-dive/) for more details .

You could refer to document :[Integrate Azure AD with an Apache Cordova app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova)

Comment: Hi Nan Yu, 
thanks for your answer. But I'm still not sure which adal Version to use....the  one for Angular or the Cordova plugin. What I would like to reach is an Angular Application which I can also compile with Cordova to a hybrid app. 

Is this possible, or do I have to differ between the HTML/Angular app and the  Corodova app (Which uses it's specific kind of adal) ? 

Best Regards 
Michael

Comment: I suggest using adal for cordova for accessing native resource ,please refer to [this blog](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/04/06/adal-plugin-for-apache-cordova-deep-dive/) , it includes topic about why adal for cordova would be better than adal.js in cordova app .

Comment: Thanks for this. So I decided to use the Angular version in the Angular app and use the Cordova Plugin on the other hand when I compile the angular app for mobile devices with Cordova.